# Pycharm, virtualenv and kivy setup

Tags: python, pycharm, kivy

I'm moving to pycharm from sublime text and can't get it working with kivy and virtualenv. I've created a virtualenv with a new project in pycharm but I can't figure out how to get kivy working. The kivy help shows using the kivy.bat as the python interpreter but I want to use the virtualenv. One possible option would be to add all the environmental variables from the kivy.bat, but this doesn't sound like fun to do with multiple virtualenvs. Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to set the environmental variables found in the kivy.bat. I simply created a new .bat that sets the environmental variables and then runs pycharm from the command line. This allows the variables to persist between projects.