# SetUp kivy & anaconda with pycharm IDE on OSX

Tags: python, macos, pycharm, kivy, anaconda

### The problem:

**Setting up `kivy` to work with `anaconda` in `pycharm`**

### What I have done:

Following the directions found at [Connecting Kivy with Anaconda (OSX)](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Connecting-Kivy-with-Anaconda-%28OSX%29) I have `kivy` working with `anaconda` (it launches via the `kivy.app`, not from `conda`)

Following those: [Setting Up Kivy with various popular IDE's](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Setting-Up-Kivy-with-various-popular-IDE's) I set up `anaconda` in `Pycharm`.

**However, I need to use `kivy` *and* `anaconda` in `pycharm`.

Does someone know how to set it up?**

`----------------------------------------------------------------------------------`

### Additional information

It may be useful to know that launching kivy via a `conda environment` (`$ source activate ...`) does not work; it throws an `import error/package kivy not installed`

The final 'bootstrapping script' for the `kivy.app` is as follows (modified from [Connecting Kivy with Anaconda (OSX)](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Connecting-Kivy-with-Anaconda-%28OSX%29))

```
#!/bin/bash
SCRIPT_PATH="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}";
if([ -h "${SCRIPT_PATH}" ]) then
  while([ -h "${SCRIPT_PATH}" ]) do SCRIPT_PATH=`readlink "${SCRIPT_PATH}"`; done
fi
SCRIPT_PATH=$(python -c "import os; print(os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname('${SCRIPT_PATH}')))")

# activate the virtualenv
# SUPPRESSED
# source ${SCRIPT_PATH}/venv/bin/activate

# setup the environment to not mess with the system
export PYTHONPATH="${SCRIPT_PATH}/kivy:${PYTHONPATH}"
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="${SCRIPT_PATH}/lib"
export LD_PRELOAD_PATH="${SCRIPT_PATH}/lib"
export GST_REGISTRY="${SCRIPT_PATH}/gst.registry"
export GST_PLUGIN_SCANNER="${SCRIPT_PATH}/gst-plugin-scanner"
export GTK_PATH="${SCRIPT_PATH}/../Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/Current"
export GST_PLUGIN_SYSTEM_PATH="${SCRIPT_PATH}/../Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/Current/lib/gstreamer-1.0"
export GST_PLUGIN_SYSTEM_PATH="${SCRIPT_PATH}/../Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/Current/lib/gstreamer-1.0"
export GIO_EXTRA_MODULES="${SCRIPT_PATH}/../Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/Current/lib/gio/modules"
export KIVY_HOME="${SCRIPT_PATH}/.kivy"

# activate the conda environment
# ADDED
source activate kivy

# if an app is available, use it
# SUPPRESSED
# if [ -d "${SCRIPT_PATH}/yourapp" ]; then
#   cd "${SCRIPT_PATH}/yourapp"
#   if [ -f "main.so" ]; then
#       exec ${SCRIPT_PATH}/python -c "import main"
#     exit 1
#   fi
#     if [ -f "main.pyo" ] || [ -f "main.opt-2.pyc" ]; then
#         exec ${SCRIPT_PATH}/python -OO -m main "$@"
#     exit 1
#     else
#         exec ${SCRIPT_PATH}/python -m main "$@"
#     exit 1
#     fi

# ADDED
if [ $# -ne 0 ]; then
    exec python "$@"
else
    exec python
fi

# default drag & drop support
elif [ $# -ne 0 ]; then
        exec ${SCRIPT_PATH}/python "$@"

# start a python shell, only if we didn't double-clicked
# SUPPRESSED
# elif [ "$SHLVL" -gt 1 ]; then
#         exec ${SCRIPT_PATH}/python
fi
```

I also [raised the issue with kivy](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/4370) on github

### The following SO questions did not help:

- [kivy with pycharm import error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15444116/kivy-with-pycharm-import-error)
- [How to configure Python Kivy for PyCharm on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016259/how-to-configure-python-kivy-for-pycharm-on-windows)
- [kivy with pycharm import error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15444116/kivy-with-pycharm-import-error?rq=1)
- [Pycharm, virtualenv and kivy setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30787397/pycharm-virtualenv-and-kivy-setup?rq=1)